# Matrix operations for arbitrary data types in C

Tags: c, matrix

Say I have some function that performs a matrix operation (like a transpose) on a `float` array:

```
void transpose(float *result, const float *input, int rows, int cols){

    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            result[rows*j+i] = input[cols*i+j];
        }
    }

}
```

This function will work for any data type with size `sizeof(float)`. Can this function be modified to work with arrays of arbitrary data type, or is it necessary to have separate functions for each data type of different size (e.g. `transpose_8`, `transpose_32`, etc.)?

Comment: Pass `void` pointers instead, pass size of your data, use the size to calculate pointer offsets and use `memcpy` instead of assignment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks, I knew there was something obvious I was missing. Make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: While generic matrix transposition routines can be implemented, matrix transposition is a notorious performance problem, and performance can be expected to suffer considerably for a generic routine if the matrix sizes are substantial. In this case, attempting to be generic would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this function be modified to work with arrays of arbitrary data type?

Yes, you can pass a generic `void *` pointer and the size of a single element as a parameter, which is exactly how [`qsort()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) handles any kind of data type ([source](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/qsort.c.html)).

Here's a working example:

```
void transpose(void *result, const void *input, size_t rows, size_t cols, size_t element_size) {
    unsigned char *input_ptr = (unsigned char *)input;
    unsigned char *result_ptr = (unsigned char *)result;
    size_t i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            unsigned char *in = input_ptr + element_size * (cols * i + j);
            unsigned char *res = result_ptr + element_size * (rows * j + i);
            memcpy(res, in, element_size);
        }
    }
}
```

---

You could also do this in-place using the same swapping technique as `qsort()` does:

```
void transpose_inplace(void *input, size_t n, size_t element_size) {
    unsigned char *input_ptr = (unsigned char *)input;
    size_t i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            unsigned char *a = input_ptr + element_size * (n * i + j);
            unsigned char *b = input_ptr + element_size * (n * j + i);
            size_t size = element_size;

            while (size--) {
                unsigned char tmp = *a;
                *a++ = *b;
                *b++ = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using `n` here since to transpose in-place you need a square matrix where `rows = cols = n`.

Comment: Transpose was given as an example. This is a specific solution.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie It's exactly what OP asked for. The example is only done to show how the generic function could be implemented. The second example is done to further explain how swapping could be implemented when needed instead of just copying. I don't really get what's the problem here.

Comment: But swapping is a part of the transpose operation. That is why it is called "transpose". Any other matrix operation is not supported by your solution. What is the generic solution to operate on matrices of any type, for any matrix operation that must be supported?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie read the function signature more carefully. The function given in OP's post does not require any kind of swapping. That's why a single `memcpy()` is enough to do the job. However, if doing an operation that involves in-place modification, a proper swap needs to be performed. That's why I wrote the two functions.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie by your logic the other answer should also not be ok. My solution was given as an example to how to transform OP's code. It's obviously impossible to implement a "generic matrix operation" function.

Comment: I was thinking more of a generic signature and approach. But your answer is very fine.

Answer (score 2):

From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065699/matrix-operations-for-arbitrary-data-in-c#comment106232212_60065699) by [Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253229/eugene-sh), you can pass `void *`, the size of the data, and the size of the types you're passing so it works for all types.

You have to convert these to `char *` so you can use pointer arithmetic, though.

Here's how you can do that:

```
void transpose(void *result, const void *input, int size, int rows, int cols)
{    
    int i, j;
    char *r = result;
    const char *i = input;

    for( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
        {
            memcpy(r + size * (rows * j + i), i + size * (cols * i + j), size);
        }
    }

}
```